# angular nested state uirouter not loading template

Tags: angularjs

With the following code, I'm trying to create a page with the url /admin, that would lead you to /admin/devices after clicking a button and after clicking another button to /admin/devices/new. The first part works properly and I get redirected to /admin/devices. The second part not quite, since it changes the url to /admin/devices/new but it doesn't change the template. 
To change through url's I use `$state.go(admin.devices)` and `$state.go(admin.devices.new)`

Any idea?

```
$stateProvider
    .state('admin', {
        url: '/users',
        abstract: true
    })
    .state('admin.devices', {
        url: '/devices',
        template: require('../templates/admin/devices/index.html'),
        controller: 'AdminDevicesCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    })
    .state('admin.devices.new', {
        url: '/new',
        template: require('../templates/admin/devices/new.html'),
        controller: 'AdminDevicesNewCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    });
```

Comment: Does '../templates/admin/devices/index.html' have a <ui-view> element within it? Since 'admin.devices.new' is a child state of 'admin.devices', I believe it requires that to display the child state's template.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, there was no <ui-view> element withing it. Thanks!